# Timestamp expired when triggering an event with pusher on localhost

Tags: laravel

am using laravel 5.4 and i have set up everything correctly regarding pusher and real time but ended with this  screen

[image]

what am missing and please help !

Comment: try to see this solution.
https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/event-broadcasting-not-working-with-pusher

Comment: i saw the solution they are talking about local time and server time  as well as i checked my Timezone setting in app.php it was set to UTC the standard  ...